# Call a Non-Static Method in Another Project and Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods, private-methods

I have two Windows forms applications that belong to separate solutions. I'm trying to call a method from one using the other. I created a class library from the solution I'm trying to access (Sol1) and referenced it in the project I'm running (Sol2) but I'm having difficulty accessing the method.

I found this [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met) that suggests doing it this way:

`string s = string InvokeStringMethod3
            ("TheProject", "TheNamespace", "TheClass", "TheMethod");`

```
public static string InvokeStringMethod3(
                        string assemblyName,
                        string namespaceName,
                        string typeName,
                        string methodName)
{
    Type calledType = Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + typeName + "," + assemblyName);
    String s = (String)calledType.InvokeMember(
                    methodName,
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | 
                        BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
}
```

When I run it, I get a `NullReferenceException` where `calledType` is null. According to the comments, this will only work on `static` methods but the method I'd trying to call is `public void`.

Is there a way to modify this to work for a non-static method? Or should this be done another way? I'm working with C# in Visual Studio 2015, and both projects are .NET.

Comment: why don't you just instantiate the class this method belongs to?

Comment: Do you understand what the difference is between a static method and an instance (non-static) method? You need to understand the difference between the two, not just to answer this question, but to learn C#.

Comment: @EdPlunkett If I understand it correctly (which I might not, I'm new to C#), static stays the same every time you run the program, instance doesn't.

Comment: You could also just reference the compiled DLL of the other solution...

Comment: @AxxieD - no, that's not it. You are thinking of constant or readonly which is something different entirely.

Comment: @AxxieD - This is a good write up on the MSDN site that should describe what the differences are with plenty of examples: [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: Maybe there is a good reason why this method is private, you know encapsulation. I think you should talk with author of class that contains method that you try to call, maybe there is other better way for you to use that API...

Comment: Just by fact the method is private what you want is not possible

Comment: @PaulSwetz I made a mistake, it's `public void`, not `private`. I corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object of the class and use its function when you have already referenced the solution. No need to to create a method static. Inside solution 2 instantiate your solution 1class.

```
Sol1.MyClass cls = new Sol1.MyClass();
```

Then you can use the method.

```
cls.somemethod();
```

`Static` members belong to the class not to the object and Can be used directly by class name.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Down vote for posting an answer like a comment.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!